# enumerating all partitions in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Like `Select[Tuples[Range[0, n], d], Total[#] == n &]`, but faster?

**Update**

Here are the 3 solutions and plot of their times, IntegerPartitions followed by Permutations seems to be fastest. Timing at 1, 7, 0.03 for recursive, FrobeniusSolve and IntegerPartition solutions respectively

```
partition[n_, 1] := {{n}};
partition[n_, d_] := 
  Flatten[Table[
    Map[Join[{k}, #] &, partition[n - k, d - 1]], {k, 0, n}], 1];
f[n_, d_, 1] := partition[n, d];
f[n_, d_, 2] := FrobeniusSolve[Array[1 &, d], n];
f[n_, d_, 3] := 
  Flatten[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[n, {d}, Range[0, n]], 1];
times = Table[First[Log[Timing[f[n, 8, i]]]], {i, 1, 3}, {n, 3, 8}];
Needs["PlotLegends`"];
ListLinePlot[times, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegend -> {"Recursive", "Frobenius", "IntegerPartitions"}]
Exp /@ times[[All, 6]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your function:

```
In[21]:= g[n_, d_] := Select[Tuples[Range[0, n], d], Total[#] == n &]

In[22]:= Timing[g[15, 4];]

Out[22]= {0.219, Null}
```

Try [FrobeniusSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FrobeniusSolve.html):

```
In[23]:= f[n_, d_] := FrobeniusSolve[ConstantArray[1, d], n]

In[24]:= Timing[f[15, 4];]

Out[24]= {0.031, Null}
```

The results are the same:

```
In[25]:= f[15, 4] == g[15, 4]

Out[25]= True
```

You can make it faster with [IntegerPartitions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/IntegerPartitions.html), though you don't get the results in the same order:

```
In[43]:= h[n_, d_] := 
 Flatten[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[n, {d}, Range[0, n]], 1]
```

The sorted results are the same:

```
In[46]:= Sort[h[15, 4]] == Sort[f[15, 4]]

Out[46]= True
```

It is much faster:

```
In[59]:= {Timing[h[15, 4];], Timing[h[23, 5];]}

Out[59]= {{0., Null}, {0., Null}}
```

Thanks to phadej's fast answer for making me look again.

Note you only need the call to [Permutations](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Permutations.html) (and [Flatten](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Flatten.html)) if you actually want all the differently ordered permutations, i.e. if you want

```
In[60]:= h[3, 2]

Out[60]= {{3, 0}, {0, 3}, {2, 1}, {1, 2}}
```

instead of

```
In[60]:= etc[3, 2]

Out[60]= {{3, 0}, {2, 1}}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
partition[n_, 1] := {{n}}
partition[n_, d_] := Flatten[ Table[ Map[Join[{k}, #] &, partition[n - k, d - 1]], {k, 0, n}], 1]
```

This is even quicker than FrobeniusSolve :)

Edit: If written in Haskell, it's probably clearer what is happening - functional as well:

```
partition n 1 = [[n]]
partition n d = concat $ map outer [0..n]
  where outer k = map (k:) $ partition (n-k) (d-1)
```